# Discrete math: how to prove multiples are divisible by the same number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

This one problem has been bothering me for a while because it seems too easy:
given $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, if $z$ divides $x$, then $z$
divides $xy$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I suggest applying the definition of $z $ divides $x$

Answer (score 1):

Since $z \mid x$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mz = x$. Hence, 
$$xy = (mz)y = (zm)y = z(my),$$
where $my \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $z \mid xy$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use this idea, ($a,b,c$ are three positive integers), if $c$ divides $ab$, then either $c$ divides $a$, or $c$ divides $b$, or both.